# Chrome Apps to Web Apps

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications

Chrome says it will not be supporting Chrome-Apps in the near future except in some special cases. They say convert to web-apps.

1. Will we be able to do in-app-purchases paid in the Chrome-store with our new web apps?
2. Will Chrome be listing these new web-apps on their site?
3. Are there any other places where you can sell in app purchases for your website?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore says "Chrome Web Store payment methods are not available for websites", and doesn't say that it's going to change.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that is the case, but if I have a web-app, ie just a single page html app, as opposed to a chrome-app, how do I integrate that into the Chrome Store. Ie, Chrome are saying move away from Chrome Apps to Web Apps (ie do not use their Chrome APIs, just use standard html/javascript), which is fair enough, but how do I get my Web App (ie just a single html page) into their store now, with in-app purchases?